# Rewrite rule in subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Rewrite rule does not work on remote host in subdirectory.

While in production phase, I had this directory `http://localhost/prj/`. I used RewriteRule to "hide" and "load" PHP files without extension. This is the `.htaccess` I've used:

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

So, that worked fine, I've developed the project and I wanted to upload it to my VPS for remote use and such. The thing is, the project is still in beta, and I don't keep it in root directory ATM but at subdirectory /beta/, so now, this my URL right now is like this: `http://example.com/beta/`.

Yet when I tried to access that URL, the index.php is automatically loaded, but when I access for example file play.php as `http://example.com/beta/play` it doesn't work but it worked while the project was in production.

This is what I have tried:

- To use RewriteBase to /beta/
  `RewriteBase /beta/`
- To use different options
  `Options All -Indexes -MultiViews`
- To use directory before actual RewriteRule
  `RewriteRule ^/beta/(.*)$ $1.php`
- To use operatives `[L, QSA]`

Example:

```
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /beta/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]  



Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^/beta/(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Returned error is 404 Not found.
Edit: I'm I supposed to have  too inside apache2.conf?

Comment: Is this htaccess file in your document root or in the beta folder?

Comment: It's in beta folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `/beta/.htaccess`:

```
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /beta/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/beta/$1\.php -f [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just tried it, same thing. Should I add another <Directory /var/www/beta/> inside apache2 config file?

Comment: The .htaccess is placed excatly in that directory (beta). I tried simple index: `http://example.com/beta/index`, does not work. With `.php` ext it works fine. I also tried another version by adding /beta at the last line like `RewriteRule ^beta/(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]`. No difference, error 404.

Comment: I doubt if this htaccess is even enabled, try updated code first. If doesn't work then verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: Whoops, there we go with debugging. It doesn't return err code 500 at all. Let me check Apache config file.

Comment: I guess this was my mistake: `[Tue Mar 10 18:20:27.105854 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 15248] [client 188.127.125.19:59239] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/beta/.htaccess`

Comment: Wow thank you very much. I didn't override the defaults in Apache configuration. I'll upvote your answer for help. The code I posted in question does work otherwise without problem.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out. If it helped solving your problem you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.